# How do I prevent 2 buttons from animating at the same time?

Tags: java, android

I need your help!

Well... I was using `setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener{...});` to animate a sequence of buttons which will only blink once.

For example, if I have button1, button2, and button3 in the list to blink, so I want something like:

**button1 blink**---> **button2 blink** ---> **button 3 blink**

And that works fine, but if I try to animate the same button twice in a roll, it just blinks at the same time as the third. Something like this happens if i have button1,button1, and button2.

**button1 blink** ---> **button1 blink and button2 blink**

when it should go:

**button1 blink** ---> **button 1 blink** ---> **button2 blink**

**Code:**

```
public void animate(ArrayList<Animation> list){

    final ArrayList<Animation> listAux = new ArrayList<Animation>();
    listAux.addAll(list);

    if(listAux.size() == 1){
        animationMetod(listAux.get(0));
        listAux.remove(0);
        animate(listAux);
    }
    else if((listAux.size() >= 2)){

        listAux.get(0).setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                listAux.remove(0);

                animationMetod(listAux.get(0));
                animate(listAux);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

    } else {
        listAux.clear();
    }
}

public void animationMetod(Animation buttonBlink) {
    if(buttonBlink == button1Blink){
        button1.startAnimation(button1Blink);

    }else if(buttonBlink == button2Blink) {
        button2.startAnimation(button2Blink);

    }else if(buttonBlink == button3Blink) {
        button3.startAnimation(button3Blink);
    }
}
```

And here is the xml for blink:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="1" />
</set>
```